# Почему бы не награждать репутацией за полезные тревоги?

Tags: предложение, тревоги, репутация

Почему бы не награждать репутацией за полезные тревоги? Как-никак, приносится польза сообществу.

Comment: но зачем? За тревоги был badge

Comment: Любая награда должна быть обоснована. Участникам с репутацией `<2000` дают её за правки. Почему? Мне кажется, потому чувствуется их дефицит. Оформление вопросов до сих пор очень низкого качества. Правки нужны здесь и сейчас, к тому же их делать не так просто.

Comment: С тревогами дело обстоит иначе. Тревоги быстро обрабатываются сообществом. Если что-то серьёзное, то можно кинуть тревогу модератору, тогда вопрос будет решён в течение минут 5. Если назначить за них награду, то тогда дело только ухудшится. Вместо правок и уточнений будет прилетать раза в 3 больше тревог на "низкое качество" и "непонятную суть вопроса", что совсем не нужно и лишь помешает их обработке.

Comment: В таком случае можно снимать репутацию за бесполезные тревоги.

Comment: Есть золотой знак "Прокурор" для этого, присвоен всего 33 раза (на момент комментария)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похожий тред на MSE: [Why there isn't reputation points for successful flagging?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80852/260198)

Тревоги - это не *нормальная активность*. Это прямо противоположно нормальному функционированию сайта.

Тревоги, по большей части, нужны, чтобы привлечь внимание модераторов. Т.е, тут следует проводить аналогию с правками (за которые дают репу, если у вас `< 2000` репы).

Правки - это **улучшение качества контента**, тревоги же указывают на какие-то **проблемы**. Для правок и других вещей, за которые даётся репутация, нужен какой-никакой технический бекграунд. Для тревог, в целом, нет. Т.е, это бы выглядело странно, когда на сайте специалистов кто-то набивает репу не своими знаниями по сути. Это могло бы быть обидно тем, кто зарабатывает репу на ответах.

Ну и да, если поощрять флаганье репой, то, мне кажется, найдутся те, кто захотят заабьюзить этот механизм.

Comment: ну формально, для правок запятых не нужен технический бэкграунд :)

Comment: @Grundy такие правки будут отклоняться в очереди как несущественные (я надеюсь).

Comment: Если кроме запятых еще будут опечатки - то вполне существенные

Comment: @Suvitruf а как же "казнить нельзя помиловать"?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если увижу такое, скажу (:

Comment: @Stranger, плохой пример, там запятую должен поставить автор, иначе можно исказить смысл. Такая правка должна быть отклонена :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну не знаю, мне кажется неопределенность хуже ошибки, ошибку найдут или поправят или отклонят, те, кто разбираются в вопросе с большей вероятностью, чем не разбирающийся в вопросе сможет решить неопределенность...