# Почему бы не награждать новичков за голоса "за" хотя бы в своих вопросах?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, репутация

Почему бы не предоставить новичкам с репутацией до 250-500 получать символические +2 балла за голоса "за", как это сделано с редактированием и принятием чужих ответов?

[Недавно велось обсуждение на тему баллов за правильные тревоги](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9353/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8):

> Тревоги - это не нормальная активность. Это прямо противоположно
>   **нормальному функционированию сайта**.

[Также можно опереться на вот этот вопрос на мете enSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> As a registered user, your reputation on the site is a part of your
>   identity on the site. **It reflects**, to an extent, your
>   **familiarity with the site**, the amount of subject matter expertise you have and the level of respect your peers have for you.

и

> When everyone is at 1, where does the reputation start? There are four
>   ways a new user can earn their first bit of reputation:
>
> Make a post that gets upvotes.
>
> ...
>
> Users have their answers accepted or are the ones accepting answers
>   from other users
>
> Suggested edits are approved

Т.е. комьюнити на полном серьезе считает, что новички, которые иногда не понимают, как принять ответ, смогут найти кнопку edit и как-то *положительно* повлиять контент?

---

Вернее не так, я не имею ничего против баллов за редактирование - это наоборот круто, я просто не совсем понимаю, почему точно такая же "положительная" для контента процедура, как +1 на ответе/вопросе не дает таких же преимуществ?

---

*А как же накрутка?*

Да в принципе никак, ограничение награды за плюсы только на своих вопросах/суточный лимит. Кто вот прямо рвется накрутить себе баллы и так сможет накрутить их себе через редактирование.

---

### Зачем и что это даст?

1. Прибавит желания поставить +1 на чужой ответ, при этом накрутить кому-то репутацию не получится из-за кулдауна или ограничения на свой вопрос
2. Позволит новичкам быстрее набрать репутации на минимально-полный набор привилегий (один раз я встретил человека, который хотел отметить правильный ответ, но ему не хватало репутации, голосов на вопросе ему не хватало просто потому что метка полумертвая).
3. Возможно, прибавит стимула новичкам. Самый субъективный аргумент, но все же.

Comment: Сейчас те же новички получают балы за принятие ответа на свой вопрос. Принимают ли ответы большинство из них? Нет.

Answer (score 5):

Можно и награждать. Вопрос в том, нужно ли это.

Мне кажется, что новые пользователи, которые видят ценность сайта, и быстро соображают что к чему, не будут испытывать проблем с тем, чтобы достичь "минимально-полного набора привилегий" (как вы выразились).

Они будут продолжать комфортно пользоваться сайтом и дальше с целью самообразования, или с целью оказания помощи другим. Думаю, для них увеличение репутации будет чем-то вроде "побочного эффекта" использования сайта.

С другой стороны, есть новые пользователи, которые заходят на огонёк с вопросами типа "Срочно помогите, нужен работающий код". Им всё равно какая у них репутация, и существует ли она вообще. Скорее всего, им также всё равно и на предоставленный им ответ - главное, чтобы он работал (тогда они смогут сдать свой зачёт/экзамен/лабораторную работу), а разбираться в нём они не будут, потому что им этого не надо.

Я считаю, что можно сделать то, что вы предлагаете, но будет ли от этого реальная польза?

Comment: Согласен, с самого начала нужно понять, что сайтом нельзя пользоваться ради репутации. Есть более  серьезные цели_помогать и получать пользу. Не считаю, что это нужно ...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, по такой логике репутацию вообще можно отключить. Хотя забавно то, что именно с помощью дополнительной репутации через конкурсы.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker,  по такой логике репутация просто выдвигается на второй план, но она нужна, так же, как нужны оценки в школе и размер зарплаты на работе. Второй план  не делает его не нужным...

Comment: Не соглашусь, оценки в школе - единица измерения ума человека для вузов, а зарплата - это вообще цена за час жизни человека. Репутация же абсолютно ничего не дает, кроме **может быть** дополнительного бонуса при устройстве на работу.